# Static Web Assets over CDN and Optimal Number of Hosting Aliases

Tags: cdn

What is the optimal number of host aliases (i.e. `storage-1.host`, `storage-2.host`, etc.) to have with a content delivery network? I'm using Amazon Cloud Front and can set up to 10 different CNAME records. My understanding is that browsers will initiate two parallel connections to any given host, but I'm wondering if browsers will connect to an unlimited number of different hosts or is a limit set in place? I have taken a look through a few large services (such as YouTube and Flickr) and noticed that they tend to use 4 different host aliases. Is this the optimal number? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the ideal number is 10, then. :)

The more hosts you have, the better - the whole idea is that you want as many downloads running in parallel as possible, and more hosts = more parallel downloads.

Comment: Won't this then require multiple DNS lookups as well? I am not convinced that this is true. Have you ever implemented large scale CDN infrastructures?

Comment: The CDN implementations I've dealt with have generally been a combination of cloudfiles and whatever other servers we needed to throw into the mix - while there are more DNS lookups for more hostnames, the parallelized downloads make up for a bigger speed increase than the DNS lookups make for a speed decrease.

Comment: Great thanks for the advice. The service is just downloading image thumbnails (so they are relatively small) but it looks like I might have to do some experimentation to find the optimal number.

Comment: Yeah - CDN's are a huge YMMV area. Requirements for things like video vs. photos vs. js are all different - good luck with your experiments!